# Why am I getting null on a method to delete an Android TableRow?

Tags: java, android, null, tablerow

**Problem:** I have two `TableLayouts` that have delete row buttons in each `TableRow`. When the `deleteTableRows()` method is called, it has no issue deleting rows for the **FILES** table, but it fails with a `null` object error on the **AUTHOR** table. I've been debugging for hours and can't identify the `null` causing the issue? I was hoping someone may see what I can't.

**What I have done:** I've had this working for months but I felt it necessary to split a `setupDeleteRowButton` method into two separate methods because I needed independent control of `layoutParam` adjustments for each `TableLayout`. I figured I could refactor later. Otherwise, the two methods are virutally identical.

I have a `deleteTableRow()` method that deletes rows from `TableLayouts` called by the `OnClickListener`. The two methods that created the `TableRows` dynamically for the `TableLayouts` add a `tag` based identifier for each row created, so when the `deleteTableRows()` method is called, the correct row is deleted based upon the `tag` identifier.

**What is happening:** I'm not seeing any `null`s debugging? When I delete a **File** table row, using the tag as you see in the `deleteTableRows()` method below - no issue! When I do with the **Author** table, I get a *'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object* reference -- but I'm not seeing it? Confused? I've check for null on the `table`, `tblRow` and `tag` variables and nothing is null.

**I've included the working "File" version to compare to the "Author" version of code. I'm still learning Android, so my methods may be a bit clumsy. The TableLayouts are created at the XML activity and all rows added dynamically... including headers.

**The delete method** it fails here on the `if` statement this method is called by the `setup[table]DeleteRowButton()` methods

```
public static void deleteTableRows(TableLayout table, String tag){
    for (int i=1; i < table.getChildCount(); i++){
        TableRow tblRow = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
        if(tblRow.getTag().toString().equals(tag)) {
            table.removeView(tblRow);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm seeing and receiving these on the `if` statement above** This is row 187 in the error below and row 167 in the method call by the `OnClickListener` in the code below

[image: variables]

[image: error]

**The two `setup[table]DeleteRowButton` methods** (the OnClickListeners are setup the same, passing a unique tag) - called by the `setup[table]TableRow()` methods

I'm not sure I have an issue with either of these but the "File" version's call to the `deleteTableRows()` has not issue, the call from the "Author" version apparently does? They both pass `String` tags, and so the `.toString()` is used.

```
public static Button setupFileDeleteRowButton(Context context, TableLayout table, String tag){
    Button btnDelete = new Button(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams trLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    trLayoutParams.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
    trLayoutParams.weight = 1;
    trLayoutParams.height =75;
    btnDelete.setLayoutParams(trLayoutParams);
    btnDelete.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    btnDelete.setText("-");
    btnDelete.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.BOLD);
    btnDelete.setTextSize(14);
    btnDelete.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    btnDelete.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    btnDelete.setTag(tag);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String btnTag = btnDelete.getTag().toString();
        deleteTableRows(table, btnTag);
    });
    return btnDelete;
}


public static Button setupAuthorDeleteRowButton(Context context, TableLayout table, String tag){
    Button btnDelete = new Button(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams trLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    trLayoutParams.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
    trLayoutParams.weight = 0.05f;
    trLayoutParams.height =75;
    btnDelete.setLayoutParams(trLayoutParams);
    btnDelete.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    btnDelete.setText("-");
    btnDelete.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.BOLD);
    btnDelete.setTextSize(14);
    btnDelete.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    btnDelete.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    btnDelete.setTag(tag);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String btnTag = btnDelete.getTag().toString();
        deleteTableRows(table, btnTag);
    });
    return btnDelete;
}
```

**The two methods that create and pass the table and the specific tags info** (Again, no issues with the "Files", just "Author"

```
            row.addView(setupFileDeleteRowButton(context, table, fileName));
            for(int r=1; r < 2; r++){
                row.setTag(fileName);
                row.addView(addRowTextViewToTable(context, fileName, false));
                row.setClickable(true);
            }


            row.addView(setupAuthorDeleteRowButton(context, table, DateTimestampManager.currentTimestamp()));
            for(int r=1; r<5;r++) {
                row.addView(addEditTextToTable(context, ""));
                row.setClickable(true);
                Log.e("BuildTableLayout", "addEditTextToTable");
            }
```

Comment: Try to print `tblRow.getTag()` before the `if`, that should be `null`

Comment: @QBrute - Thanks for the reply....  I can print it for FILE but not for AUTHOR. Before replying, I ran a 'pass' check on the `setTag` for both and the `OnClickListener`  of `btnTag` for both and the tag is captured and passed as a string in both cases.

Comment: I found my fix which works for both. On the `if` statement, I had to get the `Button` child position -- so it would be: -- tblRow.get**ChildAt(0)**.getTag().toString().equals(tag). I still don't see the difference as to why it worked for FILE but not AUTHOR, but it works for both.  I will post the solution.  Thanks QBrute for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my fix. I'm still at a loss as to why the previous setup worked with "FILE" version but not the "AUTHOR", but this fix works for both. That being said, it does make sense to look at the `getChildAt(0)` position since that is always the button position and receives the `setTag`. Anyhow, here is the fix. I had to include the `.getChildAt(0)` on the `tblRow` then get the tag and check.

```
public static void deleteTableRows(TableLayout table, String tag){
    for (int i=1; i < table.getChildCount(); i++){
        TableRow tblRow = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);
        if(tblRow.getChildAt(0).getTag().toString().equals(tag)) {
            table.removeView(tblRow);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```